# Continuous function in topological space

Tags: general-topology

$(X,T),(Y,V)$ are topological space
$f:X\to Y$, $g:X\to Y$ are continuous function show that $f-g$ function is continuous. I need to show with neighborhood base I try and I did it but I want to be sure.

Comment: An arbitrary topological space need not have a group structure. Maybe $Y = \Bbb R^n$?

Comment: (X,T) is undefined but (Y,V) Y=IR and $V:=\{[a,b): a,b \in R\}$

Comment: $V$ is not a topology, since it is not closed under union, nor contains $Y$. It is a basis for a topology though.

Comment: V is sorgenfrey topology I wrote wrong sorry it also known lower limit topolgy

Answer (score 1):

$f-g$ is not necessary continuous. Note that already $x \to -x$ is not continuous on $Y = \Bbb S$, the Sorgenfrey line.